# Inputting two arrays for a module in Mathematica

Tags: programming, physics

I am relatively new to the *Mathematica* enviroment and not sure where I am going wrong. I have evaluated the question and understand it, but dont know how to exactly create a module for it.

The problem is:

- I need to calculate `PowerDensity` at a location $(x,y)$
- I am given the power $P$ at the source and its location $(x2,y2)$
- To calculate the `PowerDensity`, you use $P_d= \frac{P}{4\pi r^2}$
- The two $x$ and $y$ coordinates compute to give : 
  $P_d = \frac{P}{(4*\pi*(y_2 - y_1)^2 - (x_2 - x_1)^2)}$

How do I write a `Module` like:

```
PowerDensity[antenna_, loc_] := Module[(* Enter your code here*)]
```

so the user would enter e.g. `PowerDensity[{1000,1000,12}, {0,0}]`?

So far I have this:

```
PowerDensity[antenna_, loc_] := Module[{xone, yone, w} {xtwo, ytwo},
    PD = w/(4*Pi*(ywo - yone)^2 - (xtwo - xone)^2),
    print[PD]
]
```

But it is not working.
Any help?

Comment: Where's the power in `PowerDensity[{1000,1000,12}, {0,0}]`? You might be interested in the function `SquaredEuclideanDistance[]`...

Comment: {1000,1000,12} is {xone,xtwo, and the power}

Comment: {0,0} is the location where we want to find the powerdensity..so the x and y of that point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things I see right away:

- Whatever function you create inside the `Module` needs to depend on the variables `antenna` and `loc`.  Figure out whether `antenna` and `loc` will be lists of numbers or just numbers.  If they are lists, like a pair of $x$ and $y$ numbers, then your function will have to depend on `antenna[[1]]`, `antenna[[2]]`, etc.
- Also, you have the structure for [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html) wrong.  To figure out how a built-in function works, try typing

  ```
  ?Module
  ```

  and the *Mathematica* help function will show you how to use `Module`.  Try building the simplest `Module` that you can, just so you know how the function works, then once you have a working example you can modify it to deal with the physics problem above.

ETA: I think your last formula is wrong (try and figure out what $r$ is in terms of the two given coordinates).  You have two commas in the Module environment, where the second one should be a semicolon.  And finally, the Print function must have its first letter capitalized just like any built-in mathematica function.

I don't know what the policy is around here about answering homework questions.  I was trying to walk you to the answer without actually giving it, but I don't know that you'll get there from where you are.  I would write the function the following way:

```
PowerDensity[antenna_, loc_] := Module[{r, power},
 r = Sqrt[(antenna[[1]] - loc[[1]])^2 + (antenna[[2]] - loc[[2]])^2];
 power = antenna[[3]];
 power/(4 Pi r^2)]
```

Comment: Antenna will be plain {x,y, power}, loc will be {x,y}.. that is a list yeah?

Comment: Both of those are lists.  Inside Module, you'll call power as antenna[[3]].  xone would be antenna[[1]], and so on.

Comment: no actually they are just numbers

Comment: ohh okay, i see

Comment: i'll try that right now, thanks! :)

Comment: does that also mean, i can simply type in the formula and refer to the variables in the equation as antenna[[3]] etc etc?

Comment: As an example, if you defined f[x_] := x[[1]] + x[[2]] + x[[3]];  , then f[{1,2,3}] would return 6.  Doing the same inside a module is straightforward.

Comment: yes i understand, but the syntax of this inside a module..how will that go? i have currently now.. Module[
 PD = antenna[[3]]/(4*
      Pi*(loc[[2]] - loc[[1]])^2 - (antenna[[2]] - antenna[[1]])^2),
 print[PD]
 ]

Comment: and this is giving it correctly, but it is not evaluating the equation.. just need to get it to evaluate..do i apply  f[{1,2,3}] here now instead of print[PD]?

Comment: You still have Module structured wrong.  Look at the first line that comes up when you type ?Module.  If that doesn't help, highlight the word Module and hit F1, and the Help page will open up.  There is a working example of a Module function, copy it and paste it into your notebook, then modify it to be what you want.

Comment: Then you need to remove that comma before the print command. Commas have specific uses in Mathematica, and here I think you just want to end the line and start a new one, in which case you use a semicolon.

Comment: this is what the question has provided *** PowerDensity[antenna_, loc_] := Module[(* Enter your code here*)]  ****

Comment: The `r^2` factor is easily computed using the `SquaredEuclideanDistance[]` function, of course.

Comment: I think here, since this is obviously a homework problem, Daniel should think about what $r$ is in the formula, how it is defined in terms of the coordinates.  In the last formula above, he has two errors which indicate he's unsure about the definition of r.  Using builtin functions like SquaredEuclideanDistance is fine only if you already know how to calculate the squared Euclidean distance.  If not, I don't think it's helpful. Defining $r$ first is a good illustration of the usefulness of Module.

Comment: Also, I didn't know about the SquaredEuclideanDistance function, but it seems like it is easier to type Norm[a - b]^2 than SquaredEuclideanDistance[a, b].