# local variable naming & symbolic argument

Tags: syntax, variable-definitions, homework

I'm stuck here with my variable assignment in this scenario

```
AntennaPower[measure_, antenna_] := 
 Module[{{x1, x2, sd1} = measure, {xa, ya} = antenna},
  N[ sd1*(4*Pi*((xa - x1)^2 + (ya - y1)^2)/1000)]]

AntennaPower[{2000, 0, 1/2}, {5, 60}]
Error message is Module::lvset: Local variable specification {{x1,x2,sd1}={2000,0,1/2},{xa,ya}={5,60}} contains {x1,x2,sd1}={2000,0,1/2}, which is an assignment to {x1,x2,sd1}; only assignments to symbols are allowed. >>
```

Comment: You can not assign to a list in local variable specification as You did {x1,x2,sd1}=measure. Use an explicit names in function declaration, eg. AntennaPower[{x1_,x2_,sd1_},{xa_,ya_}] for local variables.

Comment: Are you and this user http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13745/using-triangulation/13749#13749 the same person?

Comment: You asked the same question [earlier](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13491/5) and you were given a simple answer and asked to read some basic tutorials... did you do that? This would've been answered had you simply looked up `Module` in the documentation.

Comment: Same question, different user.  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13576/973

Answer (score 5):

The quick answer is:

```
AntennaPower[measure_List, antenna_List] := 
 Module[{x1,x2,xa,ya,sd2},
  {x1, x2, sd1} = measure;
  {xa, ya} = antenna;
  N[ sd1*(4*Pi*((xa - x1)^2 + (ya - y1)^2)/1000)]
]
```

The point here is that the first argument to Module can only be a sequence of symbols (or of assignments `x=x0,y=y0,...`) but no expressions are allowed. Just an aside: I changed your argument pattern to `_List` so that the functions only match when the arguments have the head `List`.

**Edit**

Of course there are many different ways to do what you want. mmal pointed out in his comment that you can also use

```
AntennaPower[{x1_,x2_,sd2_}, {xa_,ya}] := 
     Module[{},
      N[sd1*(4*Pi*((xa - x1)^2 + (ya - y1)^2)/1000)]]
```

In your case (where you know the length of your input lists) it is probably the wiser choice as this version only evaluates for the correct form of the input arguments.

Answer (score 4):

You can not assign to a list in local variable specification as You did `{x1,x2,sd1}=measure`. You can assign specific parts of dummy variables:

```
AntennaPower[measure_, antenna_] := 
 Module[{x1=measure[[1]], x2=measure[[2]], sd1=measure[[3]], xa=antenna[[1]], ya=antenna[[2]]},
 N[sd1*(4*Pi*((xa - x1)^2 + (ya - y1)^2)/1000)]
]
```

or use equivalent **sebhofer**'s  method. But this might be dangerous when the length of actual arguments is different. Use an explicit names in function declaration, eg.

```
AntennaPower[{x1_,x2_,sd1_},{xa_,ya_}] :=
 N[sd1*(4*Pi*((xa - x1)^2 + (ya - y1)^2)/1000)]
```

EDIT: To end this lengthy discussion You can use method proposed by **sebhofer** with argument checking by:

```
AntennaPower[measure_, antenna_] := Module[{x1, x2, sd1, xa, ya},
     {x1, x2, sd1} = measure;
     {xa, ya} = antenna;
     N[sd1*(4*Pi*((xa - x1)^2 + (ya - y1)^2)/1000)]
    ] /; (Length[measure] == 3 && Length[antenna] == 2);
```

Comment: hehe... what are we going to do now?? :)

Comment: Well it's my pleasure to return the favour!